# Checked Exception and Unchecked Exception

Tags: java

Объясните пожалуйста в чем разница между checked Exception и unchecked Exception если обе их можно поймать. дайте пример если не сложно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все исключительные ситуации делятся на «проверяемые» (checked) и «непроверяемые» (unchecked).

1. Checked исключения, это те, которые должны обрабатываться блоком catch или описываться в сигнатуре метода. Unchecked могут не обрабатываться и не быть описанными.
2. Unchecked исключения в Java — наследованные от RuntimeException, checked — от Exception (не включая unchecked).

Checked исключения отличаются от Unchecked исключения в Java, тем что:

1)Наличие\обработка Checked исключения проверяются на этапе компиляции.

2) Наличие\обработка Unchecked исключения происходит на этапе выполнения.

Пример c исключением checked FileNotFoundException, которое выбрасывается из-за используемых FileReader и BufferedReader:

```
import java.io.*;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileReader file = new FileReader("C:\\test\\a.txt");
        BufferedReader fileInput = new BufferedReader(file);

        for (int counter = 0; counter < 3; counter++) 
            System.out.println(fileInput.readLine());

        fileInput.close();
    }
}
```

В примере ниже программа скомпилируется, но выдаст при выполнении исключение unchecked ArithmeticException:

```
class Main {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      int x = 0;
      int y = 10;
      int z = y/x;
  }
}
```

Более подробно вы можете почитать [здесь](http://javastudy.ru/interview/exceptions/) и [здесь](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/checked-vs-unchecked-exceptions-in-java/).

Comment: спасибо огромное